# Где хранить словари слов в swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

Вопрос простой, но не знаю как грамотно реализовать.

Есть англо-русский словарь в котором более 3000 слов, приложение только оффлайн. Где изначально хранить эти слова? Например захардкодить в класс и при первом запуске закинуть все это дело в CoreData. Или же есть другие красивые способы реализации огромных словарей? Обязательно без интернета и подгрузки откуда либо. Все локально.

Comment: Захардкодить в файл и спарсить его в CoreData

Comment: @Vitaly такой способ я собственно и использовал. А более красивого варианта нет?

Answer (score 0):

Сохраните словарь в JSON-файл и парсите его при загрузке приложения.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "offline_data", ofType: "json") {
  do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
    // Your code here
  } catch {
    print("error")
  }
}
```